# Update tkinter widget parameters with "pointer"

Tags: python, pointers, variables, tkinter, parameters

If I create a `tkinter.Label` with parameter `fg = PRIMARY_COLOR` and than `.pack()` it, if I change the value of `PRIMARY_COLOR` variable, call the `.update()` method of the widget, foreground color will not change. I know, why this is happening, but can I somehow do, that the widget will change foreground color with the `PRIMARY_COLOR` variable change? Can I make some kind of "pointer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan said, you can't do *exactly* what you want, but you can get close.

The code below uses the `.trace` method of a StringVar to change the Label color whenever that StringVar gets changed. It uses an Entry to change the StringVar, but you don't *have* to use the Entry: any time that the StringVar is set to a new value the callback will change the config of the "hello" Label. You can type in standard color names like 'red', or hex codes like '#ff8800'.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='hello')
label.pack()

# A StringVar that changes the Label color whenever its value is changed
label_color = tk.StringVar()
label_color.trace("w", lambda *args: label.config(fg=label_color.get()))

# An Entry where we can specify the new color
tk.Label(root, text='Enter a color name or hex number').pack()
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

# Set the StringVar to the string that the user just entered
def set_colorstring(evt):
    s = evt.widget.get()
    if s:
        label_color.set(s)

e.bind("<Return>", set_colorstring)

root.mainloop()
```

You *could* use this technique to change the config of multiple widgets, but you have to do it explicitly (eg loop over a list of widgets in the callback). Unfortunately, you can't just make the `fg` attribute a StringVar and have it automatically update the color.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do what you want. You will need to call the `configure` method of every widget that uses that color.